# oracle 12c --> Transform XML Record to Table

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle12c

Greetings.
I have XML Record as follows in oracle 12c

```
<row id='1'>
 <c1>rec1</c1>
 <c2>a</c2>
 <c2>b</c2>
 <c2>c</c2>
</row>
```

The same needs to be transformed as below

```
c1      c2
---     ---
rec1    a
rec1    b
rec1    c
```

Please help

Comment: I was looking for Query that does the transformation like a table. I found the answer. Many Thanks APC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer. The below query will transform the data into table as expected

```
SELECT RECID, MULTIVALUE 
FROM <TABLE_NAME> , 
    XMLTABLE('/row/c2' PASSING <COLUMN_NAME> COLUMNS MULTIVALUE VARCHAR2(100) PATH '.');
```